# Callback to print state of kivy Switch Widget using .kv file

Tags: python-2.7, callback, kivy

As the title says, I am trying to print out the value of a Switch widget every time the value is changed. I have managed to write the callback itself, but I can't seem to figure out what arguments to pass the callback in my .kv file.

Right now I get the error that: 'callback() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)'

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '600')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch

Builder.load_file('hueLayout.kv')

class hueLayout(BoxLayout):
    pwr1_switch = ObjectProperty()


    def callback(instance, value):
        print 'instance: ', instance
        print 'value: ', value


    #pwr1_switch.bind(pwr1_switch, active=callback)

class HueController(App):
    def build(self):
        #self._app_window_size = 5, 20
        return hueLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Config.write()
    HueController().run()
```

---

```
<hueLayout>:
    #size_hint: .5, .5
    #pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    #height: '200dp'
    #width: '100dp'
    pwr1_switch: pwr1_input

    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Master'
            GridLayout:
                cols: 3

                Switch:
                    id: pwr1_input
                    active: root.callback()



        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Light 1'
            BoxLayout:

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Light 2'

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Light 3'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the actual error you have is because you have

```
def callback(instance, value):
    print 'instance: ', instance
    print 'value: ', value
```

Then later

```
               active: root.callback()
```

But the callback function takes two arguments (those you call instance and value), so naturally you get the error that you didn't provide enough.

It looks like your problem has 3 components:

1) Saying `active: root.callback()` tries to *set* the active property from the *result* of callback. That's the opposite of what you want, where you want to *call* callback() when the active property *changes*. You can instead do `on_active: root.callback()` to call the function when active changes.

2) Remember, everything on the right of a colon in kv language is just python. That means if you call a function you have to give it the right arguments, nothing is implicit. In your case, you're calling callback() with no arguments whereas it expects two. The on_active method automatically receives the two arguments I think you really want, which in kv language are accessible with the 'args' keyword as described [in the documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html). You can do `on_active: root.callback(*args)` to pass these on.

3) As a class method, callback() automatically receives the class instance as an implicit first argument, usually just called self. The instance and value are *also* passed. You can see an example in the [properties documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html), search for `on_a`. So you'll need `def callback(self, instance, value)` for it to work.

Comment: I had purposely left active: root.callback() empty because I didn't know what to put in it. But thank you, this solved my problem perfectly. I didn't understand that you could add 'on_' to a property to call when it changes.